# ASP.NET MVC DisplayFormat for Hour

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following TimeSpan variable in my Model class:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH-mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public TimeSpan StartingHour { get; set; }
```

But when I call it from my View I got the error:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartingHour)
```

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

The value of the variable is: "18:00:00".

What should be in my DisplayFormat initialization? And please keep "get hour and minute separately from the time" advices to yourself.

Comment: Try changing `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartingHour)` to `@Html.DisplayFor(item=> item.StartingHour)`

Comment: That's not the problem. I iterate with "foreach (var item in Model)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `DataFormatString =  @"{0:hh\-mm}"`

Comment: What does 0:c do exactly? I already can display it without DisplayFormat. And after your edit: I already tried that and got the same error.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan  Actually, see my updated answer.  That should work.

Comment: You've made 6 edits. When I'm writing this you've done the 7th. Please state your final answer, or do try once before stating and answer.

Comment: Now please stay steady and don't edit, I'm accepting your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
DataFormatString ="{0:hh\\:mm}"
```

Thanks.